# C# IList update issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having an issue using `IList` in C#.

I have the list inside my class, and a method that is supposed to update it.
However, once I need to display the list or update it again, I get the original list instead of the updated one.

```
 IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>{
                        new Student() { StudentId = 1, StudentName = "John", Age = 18 } ,
                        new Student() { StudentId = 2, StudentName = "Steve",  Age = 21 } ,
                        new Student() { StudentId = 3, StudentName = "Bill",  Age = 25 } ,
                        new Student() { StudentId = 4, StudentName = "Ram" , Age = 20 } ,
                        new Student() { StudentId = 5, StudentName = "Ron" , Age = 31 } ,
                        new Student() { StudentId = 6, StudentName = "Chris" , Age = 17 } ,
                        new Student() { StudentId = 7, StudentName = "Rob" , Age = 19 }
                    };

    // GET: Student
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(studentList);
    }
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Student std)
{
    var name = std.StudentName;
    var age = std.Age;
    var id = std.StudentId;

    Student stud = new Student();
    stud.Age = age;
    stud.StudentId = id;
    stud.StudentName = name;

    studentList.RemoveAt(id-1);
    Debug.WriteLine(id);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The method logs the change correctly when update is done. I have tried editing the element instead of removing it, with no avail.

How do I solve this?

Comment: You have not shown where `studentList` is initialized, but I assume its in the controller. The web is stateless. Each time a request is made a new instance of your controller is created (and a new instance of `studentList` is created). You need to persist you data somewhere (e.g. to a database)

Comment: Please post the relevant code from your `Index()` action and show how `studentList` is initialized.

Comment: @StephenMuecke that explains why the tutorial also has no code to update the dummy list. Thank you.

Comment: @itsme86 edited. Code is as seen on http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/create-edit-view-in-asp.net-mvc

Answer (score 3):

Instead of redirecting the user at the end of your Edit method, pass back the View with the updated student list. Like this:

Instead of:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Use:

```
return View("Index", studentList);
```

(Where 'Index' is the name of the view you want to display.)

Calling `RedirectToAction` reloads the class and re-initializes the `studentList` so instead of showing the updated list, it will show the original.